# Excel VBA - How do you set line style for chart series?

Tags: charts, excel, vba

I would like the plot lines in a chart to be either solid, circle dot, or square dot based upon a certain criteria specified by the user.  I can successfully set the line color and marker style for the plot using a macro, but I cannot seem to find the object which holds the value for the plot line style property.  I have tried using the record macro function, but changing the line style in the properties windows does not show up in the code, and running the recorded macro has no effect.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

```
YourChartSeries.Border.LineStyle = [some value from the XlLineStyle enumeration]
```

UPDATE: recording in XL 2010 I get this -

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .DashStyle = msoLineSysDot
End With
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .DashStyle = msoLineSysDash
End With
```

Which might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried setting the line style manually in excel and used    
    MsgBox (CurrentChart.SeriesCollection(1).Border.LineStyle)
which returns a value of -4105 regardless if the line is square dot, circle dot, dashed, etc.

Comment: You question is confusing - are you asking about the line connecting the markers, or the markers themselves? Please update your question with whatever code you have: that always helps get useful answers.

Comment: If you manually right click on a plotted series and click "format data series..." under "line style" you can change the dash type.  I wanted to be able to format the data series lines in my program as "round dot" and "square dot".  However the XLineStyle enumeration does not offer these dash options.  

I have since decided to scrap the "square dot" and "round dot" style and am using XlContinuous, XlDot, and XlDash instead.  It's not as pretty as the square and round dot, but it does the job.

Answer (score 4):

Create a chart with 255 data series, run the code (and do other formatting as necessary). Then save it as a template.

```
Sub dd()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Dim myChart As Chart
Set myChart = wb.Charts("Chart5")

Dim mySeries As series

For Each mySeries In myChart.SeriesCollection
    mySeries.Format.Line.Weight = 1#
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a line chart, I ended up creating a switch statement because I couldn't figure out how to make an array of "Name" variables. See [list of line types here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863713.aspx)

```
For j = i To num_lines_to_plot
        count = count + 1
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j)
            .Name = _
                "='"**... (you'll need to fill this in)**
            'create gradient
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 20 * count, 0)
            'modify linetype
            If count > 4 Then
                line_type = count Mod 4
            Else
                line_type = count
            End If

            Select Case line_type
                Case Is = 1
                    .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
                Case Is = 2
                    .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSquareDot
                Case Is = 3
                    .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineDash
                Case Is = 4
                    .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineLongDash
                End Select

        End With
    Next
```