# Draw in a chart (not a chart object but a Chart) with vba

Tags: vba, charts, line, draw

I'll try to be very precise with my problem but if you have any questions, please ask!

So basicelly I have a column A full of dates (from line 1 to line 80) and a column B full of values (stock prices, and also with the same range).
I have created a chart with this code :

```
Sub Chart()
   Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(80, 1))Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 1)).Select
   Set rSource=selection
   ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rSource, PlotBy:=xlColumns
   ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
end sub
```

So this is not a chart object but a new chart on a new sheet (I say that because all the things I've read on this subject is dealing with chart objects and not with chart alone in a sheet).
Now what I need is to draw an horizontal line between two dates (a support line).
For example, I need to draw a line between 01/01/2013 (line 1) and 06/25/2013 (line 80).
The line has to stay at the same level on the y-axis (that's what we call an horizontal line :) ) at the level of the stock price of 01/01/2013.

I've tried that :

```
Sub supportline()
Dim CoordA As Variant
CoordA = [a1:b80]
ActiveChart.Shapes.AddLine(CoordA(1, 1), CoordA(1, 2), CoordA(80, 1), CoordA(80, 2)).Select
end sub
```

But the line isn't drawn where I want. I think there's a problem of scale but I can't figure out how to have the accurate coordinates.

Thank you very much for your time and your help

EDIT (06/11/2013)
I've simplified the data base to illustrate my problem : http://cjoint.com/?CFksHluf0VD I'm trying to make a line between the two dates (01/01/2013 and 16/01/2013)

If you download this file, you'll see in the VBA part : 1/ Test1 : I've tried to make a line to link 2 points of the chart : if you launch the sub you'll see that the line is drawn but at the wrong scale and wrong place 2/ Test 2: I've tried to make an horizontal line between two points but that doesn't work at all

Test 2 is what I need to do for my original project (an horizontal line which goes from one date to another with the same y-value)

Comment: No it was just an example, but I'll need to draw lines that goes from two dates that aren't the first and the last datas of the serie. And i have to do it with a VBA code.

Comment: excuse me, i didn't answered to your second question. When i say sheet I mean my chart is alone in a Chart (collection). If you don't understand you can download the file on my last post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select

With Selection.Format.Line

.Visible = msoTrue
//add line style etc

End with
```

Then use your select statement to choose which points you want joined.

If you look at this link, I'll think you'll find it most useful

VBA-Controlled Conditional Formatting of Line Chart Lines

http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/conditional-formatting-of-lines-in-an-excel-line-chart-using-vba/

Another question on Stack Overflow

[Excel VBA - How do you set line style for chart series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792915/excel-vba-how-do-you-set-line-style-for-chart-series)

In response to your comments, please see the answer to this question. It offers some good explanation of using charts (in this case vb.net)

[Chart: Show more value descriptions on X-Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708974/chart-show-more-value-descriptions-on-x-axis/16807101#16807101)

And a link to MSDN re this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx

Comment: I understand what you mean but unfortunately this doesn't work :
"addline" applies to "shapes" ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221724(v=office.11).aspx )
But "shapes" can't be applied to "points" ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174305(v=office.11).aspx )

So I wrote 
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).points(1).shapes.AddLine(CoordA(1, 1), CoordA(1, 2), CoordA(80, 1), CoordA(80, 2)).Select 

But it can't work

Comment: Yes i would like some help to write the code please because I can't figure out how to do I'm sorry
The line chart has to be horizontal 

The much straightforward solution is to create a new graph with a 3rd series of data? 
So basically, if we take back my old example, I have to write the value 20 from line 1 to 16 in the column C? then select the range("A1:C20") and create a new graph?

Comment: In fact, it's working like that !!  I just have to record the macro and it'll work with VBA!! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: i can't upvote because i don't have enough reputation! thanks ! :)