# Connecting lines in MS ACCESS chart

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, graph, excel-charts

I have chart that looks like this:
[image]

And I want the user to have an option to change it to something like this:[image]

I am using this code to build it and it works perfectly fine:

```
 Me.ChartResult.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
```

However, if I use this line to get things back

```
 Me.ChartResult.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
```

I receive this result with lines connecting each point which is something I don't want to have.
[image]

I want the chart to be the same as the first one. But If i use this code:

```
With Me.ChartResult
 .ChartType = xlXYScatter
 .HasHiLoLines = True
End With
```

I receive Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

I can use only the `.ChartType = xlXYScatter`, but then I don't have these HiLoLines which i really need to have.

Comment: Why did you mention Access when you're using Excel's charting functionality?

Comment: Well I am using Access and changing chart type works. But I wasn't able to find any working code for Hi Low lines for MS Access charts. But I know that I can add them manually in chart settings. Or is there any better code I can use for this?

Comment: Possible option is two chart controls and set visibility.

Comment: Yes that is a good point thank you for it, but  if there is a way how to do it only with one chart it would be rally nice.

Comment: Maybe `.HasSeriesLines = False` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.serieslines-graph-object

Comment: No this results in the same Run-time error '438'.

Comment: Ooops, I just noticed has to be stacked-bar or column chart. Darn! Don't know if Access can handle but apparently Excel can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792915/excel-vba-how-do-you-set-line-style-for-chart-series

Comment: But what I don't understand is, that when I use this for example `.PrimaryValuesAxisMaximum = 10` then i receive the same error https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.chart.primaryvaluesaxismaximum Even though it should be part of the object according to the article

Comment: If your x-axis data is character type, you cannot create a distributed chart, and you cannot set the maximum value of the x-axis. The Excel Pivot Chart is an example of this, but depending on how your data is organized, I think you can see if it's possible.